# can asp.net run without .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, frameworks

i am very new to asp.net. I would like to ask can asp.net run without the .net framework? as in can default.aspx run smoothly without the .net framework? I am asking this due to the following existing code which was runned on a web hosting server and another is a private server. I am not sure about the private server details ( going to know in a 2-3 days)...the code goes as...

```
try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(General.SiteUrl + "/pages/" + page + ".htm");
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch { content = "<html><head></head><body>Content not found.</body></html>"; }
```

the web hosting server manage to run the "Try" successfully whereas the private one always shows content not found....any ideas guys?

Comment: though a bit of a "newbie" type question, I don't think this deserved a down-vote.

Comment: thanks....because someone mention when i asked this question. he said that .net framework is not installed. the content that i have always seems to be getting the "content not found" even though its the same code....could it be new streamreader class/dll?

Comment: try completely removing the try/catch block and take a look at the actual error code. You'll get a "yellow screen of death" that will be very informative as to what the error is. Then you can come back here, open up a new question, and find out what the error means. Also, because you're getting the `catch` code, it means that .NET **IS** installed on your machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People that *visit* your website will not need the .NET Framework; all they'll need is a browser.

The server that *runs* your website will need the .NET Framework since ASP.NET is a part of it.

The .NET Framework is required on the Server side for a few reasons (these are just some examples):

1. Your code is compiled into an intermediate language designed to be platform agnostic. A runtime (The .NET Framework) is required to convert this intermediate language into something the machine can understand. This is accomplished by the JIT.
2. There are several libraries in ASP.NET; System.Web.dll; for example. These are distributed as part of the .NET Framework.
3. The code is hosted inside of a virtual machine (in the non-traditional sense). The virtual machine takes care of a lot of heavy lifting for you; such as security; garbage collection; etc. Again; this is all part of the .NET Framework.

**EDIT**:

I think you are asking the wrong question here. You ask wondering why your code is going inside of the `catch` block and returning `Content not found.` The .NET Framework is properly installed since the catch block is being called; in fact it couldn't get nearly that far without the .NET Framework.

You need to figure out what exception is being thrown inside of the `try` block that is causing it to go into the `catch` block. You can achieve this with a debugger; logging; or temporarily removing the catch block all together to get the server to let the exception bubble all the way up to the top. For example; if you change your code block to look like this:

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(General.SiteUrl + "/pages/" + page + ".htm");
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The exception details will be displayed in the browser (provided you have debugging turned on). What error is displayed without the try / catch?

Comment: wao i have never thought of removing the try catch block. Thanks. Ill do it tomorrow morning as it is 2a.m now. Thanks a lot guys. Ill mark vcsjones as the answer as he provided a more detail to not only the main question but also the subquestion solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, .Net code will not run without support of the .Net framework. Because code written in .Net language will be compiled and converted to IL (Intermediate Language) Code.

Comment: Can IIS even exists in such an hostile environment!? Nowadays, can Windows even exists without the .Net framework? :)

Comment: Windows 7 have built in .Net framework. But some hosting server don't have .net framework installed. Server usually have Windows Server.

Comment: then can someone tell me why does content always catches "content not found" ??

Comment: Because there is an exception trying to load that URL with the WebRequest. That catch block wouldn't even be able to execute without the .NET framework. Without knowing what exception is triggering the `catch` block; it's hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework, or some variation of, e.g. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), is not required on the client side.  This is a requirement of the server which is serving the pages.

When data is sent to the client via HTTP, it is translated into HTML.  So all the client would need would be a browser capible of consuming HTML and running any scripts associated with that site.

Answer (score 0):

the .net framework is the foundation that powers this code

```
try
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(General.SiteUrl + "/pages/" + page + ".htm");
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
catch 
    { 
        content = "<html><head></head><body>Content not found.</body></html>"; 
    }
```

so in short, "no", you **must** have the .net framework installed on the server that is hosting your website.

On the other hand however, on the client side, your website visitors do NOT need the .net framework to "view" your website.